# There has been vs. There have been

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, existentials, countability

Are any of the statements below grammatically correct? If any of them is wrong, what is the correct way to state them?

> 1. There **has** been some rapid progress ...
> 2. There **has** been some rapid developments ...

or

> 1. There **have** been some rapid progress ...
> 2. There **have** been some rapid developments ...

Comment: This is going to be good explaination: http://proofreading.ie/portfolio/using-has-been-and-have-been-after-there/

Answer (score 21):

Two of your sentences are correct.

> There **has** been some rapid progress.

This is correct, because "progress" is an uncountable noun (ie. nouns that  we can't count, so don't have different plural forms); therefore, it can only take a singular verb.

> There **have** been some rapid developments.

This is correct, because "developments" is in the plural form; therefore, it needs a verb in the plural.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It should be "have been" since it has the word "SOME" meaning it is plural. We do not use has for plural nouns.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Sorry, this is simply not correct. The other answer is.

Comment: The 'some' doesn't represent a quantity as much as something that means 'less than whole'.  'I had some cake' doesn't mean I had multiple pieces of cake. It could mean I only had a part of a single piece.  To help, remove the word 'some' and see what comes next. In the first example, 'rapid progress' is a unit entity of 'progress', thus singular so you use 'has'.  In contrast 'developments' is plural, so it gets the 'have' treatment.